# Permissions in Keycloak, where can I allow all clients?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am new to Keycloak.  I have installed a Docker container with `Keycloak 19.0.2`. Then created a new realm, client and user. As described in various tutorials it says.

Now I tried to connect my Spring Boot application with Keycloak. But I always get the error connection reset.

I have now tested something around and found out something strange.

When I call the URL `/realms/rName/.well-known/openid-configuration` with Chrome or Edge I see a JSON string, same URL in Firefox I get the error `page load error`. Also Insomnia gets an error `Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer`.

I suspect that my Spring Boot application is also getting this. Now where can I set the permissions in Keycloak to allow everyone to talk to the endpoint?

Many greetings

EDIT: Same situation on Root Page. http://localhost:8080/. The Welcome Site is shown on Edge and Chrome but not in Firefox or Insomnia

Comment: .well-known/openid-configuration is not necessary permission. It can call without access-token.

Comment: No, in my case not. How I wrote, with Chrome and Edge it works, with Firefox and Insomnia not. That is my Question why?

Comment: This is [OpenID Provider Configuration](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) specification. It should be not protected API. It is not Keycloak problem. It may other's configuration problem. You can test curl without token. `curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:port/{auth or none}/realms/{your-realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration'`

Comment: Thank you I have also found 3 hours ago. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please excuse my question. I have been able to find the problem. Another process was also listening on the same port. Why there was no error that the port is already in use, I don't know. Now I set Keycloak to another port and it works with all clients. That it is technically possible at all, I wonder, especially why it is program dependent. Well, it works now. Thanks to all who helped.